# Tagging AAC problems (Kubuntu 16.04 + various apps)

Tags: audio, unicode, media, tagging

I have some AAC files which I've extracted with MP4Box form MP4 videos. I've been trying to find a (preferably GUI) application to tag them with a title, year etc. - and failing:

- Amarok - pretends to be able to edit AAC tags, not actually writing them.
- EasyTag - makes me rename the files to .mpa to notice them; then, also, supposedly tags them, but when you try to save the changes it says it fails to write the changes.
- puddletag - doesn't see AAC/M4A files
- Kid3 - Supposedly edits tags (inconvenient interface, by the way), but when you commit the changes and reload the file - they're gone.
- ExFalso - doesn't see AAC/M4A file

Is AAC tagging support really that bad? Am I doing something wrong? Should I use other apps/tools?

Comment: Supposedly [picard](https://picard.musicbrainz.org/downloads/) can do that, but I personally haven't used it with AAC files.